# Font in R console toolbar and menus is no longer correct after installing R 4.1.0

Tags: r, fonts, console

I just installed `R 4.1.0` (in French). On start of the console, the font in the console toolbar and menus is not correct (but the font displayed in the scripts are ok). Accents are replaced by incorrect characters. For example, "`Préférences`" becomes "`Prï¿½fï¿½rences`". What happened? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This isn't really a StackOverflow *programming* question.  You could try on one of the R support mailing lists.  When you do, include more information:  what OS are you running?  How did you get R?  How did you install it?

Comment: Thanks. I am running R under Windows 10. I downloaded the R installer for Windows from the CRAN R-project web site and launch it, in French version. As usual, I would say.

Comment: I will try an R support list. However, this question is also a programming question. Rconsole is an IDE, and IDEs are software. Many of the problems with IDEs are solved programmatically. Searching for questions about the Rconsole and Rstudio IDEs on stackoverflow, I found hundreds of such questions, but I couldn't find the answer to mine.